# Can I set Searchable attributes and Ranking and sorting with laravel/scout programmatically?

Tags: laravel, algolia

At https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scout#configuring-searchable-data
plugin laravel/scout used to add algolia support and reading some manuals
I found that I need to set Searchable attributes and Ranking and sorting only on algolia side ?
Can I set then "on fly" when I import my data with command ?

```
scout:import App\Models\Model"
```

?

I remember that I used such functionality, but with other package https://github.com/algolia/scout-extended.

Has laravel/scout such functionality ? This plugin seems preferable, as it is official laravel plugin...

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2",
"algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^3.4",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this something you can use? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scout#customizing-engine-searches

Comment: Thank you! second options parameter is very interesting, but I do not need any of geo_distance, location
parameters. Please give a reference to full possible option parameters as I need “Searchable attributes” and 
“Ranking and sorting” parameters...